# Jaywalking in the middle of the street

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

My admittedly sinner of a friend, who coincidentally has a court hearing tomorrow, jaywalked in the middle of a busy street to hand me the following message:

> I Was The One Who Did [ ? ] Up The [ ? ] [ ? ] To [ ? ] That [ ? ]
>
> PBA CHER ZNLBE CEBGRPG PNE YNPX FHOFRPG

[image: message]

**What did my friend tell me?** *Note that the placement of the letters in the image above are largely irrelevant in that they may serve as small hints but are not necessary to solve.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The note reads

> I was the one who did conjure up the major project to carjack that subject

Because

> using rot13(), convert the mixed up words below the letter
>  pbacher = conpure (conjure)
>  znlbe = mayor (major)
>  pneynpx = carlack (carjack)
>  fhofrpg = subsect (subject)
>  cebgrpg = protect (project)
>  Changing a letter in each word to J, changes the meaning greatly. (thx Stiv)

Title

> Jaywalking - Your friend used jaywalking to tell you to substitute the letter "J" into the exact middle of each word to create a different word.

Comment: Ah, Intentional Typos :)

Comment: @MacGyver88 You've reached stepping stone one. But 1) my friend should come across as more of the criminal type and 2) I've never known my friend to make typos.

Comment: Note that the same letter can be subbed into each of those words (not just two of them...)

Comment: @MacGyver88 Your updated answer is exactly correct - turns out my friend has a guilty conscience! I'll give you the check mark once you explain why my friend had to jaywalk in the middle of the street. (I'm curious to know if Stiv noticed this peculiarity or went by the eye test.)

Comment: @anodyne (Tbh I only took a passing look and hadn't spotted the full significance - only that in MacGyver88's list there were more words that could be tweaked in the same way...)